# Run Git Bash from Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt-creator, git-bash

Is it possible assign a shortcut for launching a Git Bash console from Qt Creator? For example, I have already assigned `Alt+G, Alt+G` to the GitGui command.

I wasn't able to find a suitable command in Options->Environment->Keyboard, but maybe I've just missed it. Or is it possible to assign shortcuts to launch a custom executable from Qt Creator? This could work for me as well.

Right now it takes me several clicks to open Git Bash for the current project, and it's a bit of an annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 .bat files, which you can place in `C:\Windows` for convenience (so they're in `%PATH%`) - `C:\Windows\StartGitBash.bat` containing `start StartGitBash2`, and `C:\Windows\StartGitBash2.bat` containing `"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`.

It might seem weird needing 2 .bat files, but you need the 2-step process in order to detach the console from Qt Creator. Otherwise Git Bash won't show a window at all (Qt Creator likely uses `QProcess::start()` instead of `QProcess::startDetached()`).

Then just [create a new External Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-external.html#configuring-external-tools) using these settings:

[image]

After that you can assign a shortcut to it the regular way - https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a VERY simple solution :

Just add a custom external tool, with following fields :

- Executable : path to the `git-bash.exe` in your Git for Windows install dir
- Arguments : leave empty
- Working directory : `%{CurrentDocument:Path}`
- Output : "Ignore"
- Error output : "Ignore"

Enjoy !